# Can't get postgresql running from Homebrew with Lion

Tags: unix, postgresql

I'm new to unix and having trouble running initdb with postgresql. I installed postgres via homebrew with "brew install postgres", and have attempted to run the initdb command as follows:

> initdb /usr/local/var/postgres 
>   The files belonging to this database
>   system will be owned by user "philhowie". This user must also own the
>   server process.
>
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale en_NZ.UTF-8. The
>   default database encoding has accordingly been set to UTF8. The
>   default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> creating directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... initdb: could not
>   create directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": Permission denied

Is postgresql supposed to run as a different user account? In that case, how do I set that up? I can't run this command as root it seems.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew deliberately doesn't do any setup for you, allowing you to do it all yourself.  Systems like MacPorts are more focused on that value-add.

So, in this case start with http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/runtime.html and follow their guidance on doing all the setup work by hand - homebrew built from source for you, but the rest is up to you.